# List all memcached keys/values

Tags: python, caching, memcached

I know this question has been asked many times and it's also covered in official memcached FAQ. But my case is - I want to use it just for admin panel purposes. I want to see keys with values in my admin page so it doesn't matter if it's slow and against the best practices. Please advise, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do it that's guaranteed to work. The only way I found is the way you'll find on google, but there's a restriction: Only 1 MB will be returned - it may not be all keys. And it will probably be quite slow..

If you really, really has to have all those keys you'd probably have to hack the source code.

I would say: no, you can't.

Why do you need all those key? I would consider redesigning your application to not make your admin panel dependent of the internals of a caching server